# Why does my Xamarin Forms ViewModel not accept a parameter passed in Xamarin Forms Shell?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am trying to pass a parameter int SxCaseId in Xamarin forms shell to another viewmodel.  I am able to see the SxCaseId value on the passing viewmodel, but it does not pass correctly to the receiving viewmodel.  I see a blank page when navigating to the receiving page.  Any help would be much appreciated.

### Passing ViewModel

```
    namespace QiX.ViewModels
{
    public class SxCaseDetailsViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ISxCaseDataService _sxCaseDataService;
        private SxCase _sxCase;
        public Command StaffCommand { get; }
        private int sxCaseId;
        private bool isEditing; 
       
        public SxCaseDetailsViewModel(IConnectionService connectionService, IDialogService dialogService,
            ISxCaseDataService sxCaseDataService) : base(connectionService, dialogService)
        {
            _sxCaseDataService = sxCaseDataService;
            
            Title = _sxCase?.Facesheet;

            
            StaffCommand = new Command(() => LoadStaff(SxCase));

            SxCases = new ObservableCollection<SxCase>();

        }


       

        async void LoadStaff(SxCase sxCase)
        {

            await Task.Delay(500);
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(
                $"{nameof(StaffView)}?{nameof(StaffViewModel.SxCaseId)}={sxCase?.SxCaseId}");
        }

        
        public ObservableCollection<SxCase> SxCases { get; set; }

        public int SxCaseId
        {
            get
            {
                return sxCaseId;
            }
            set
            {
                sxCaseId = value;
                Task.Delay(500);
                LoadSxCase(value);
                
            }
        }

        private async Task LoadSxCase(int sxCaseId)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            await Task.Delay(500);

            SxCase = await _sxCaseDataService.GetSxCasesDetail(sxCaseId);
            sxCaseId = _sxCase.SxCaseId;
            await Task.Delay(500);
            IsBusy = false;

        }

        public SxCase SxCase
        {
            get => _sxCase;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _sxCase, value);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Receiving ViewModel

```
    namespace QiX.ViewModels
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(SxCaseId), nameof(SxCaseId))]
    public class StaffViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ISxCaseDataService _sxCaseDataService;
        private IStaffDataService _staffDataService;

        private SxCaseStaffJoin _selectedSxCaseStaffJoin;
        private SxCaseStaffJoin _sxCaseStaffJoin;

        public ObservableCollection<SxCaseStaffJoin> SxCaseStaffJoins { get; set; }
        public Command LoadSxCaseStaffJoinCommand { get; }
        public Command RefreshSxCaseStaffJoinCommand { get; }

        public string sxCaseId;

        public StaffViewModel(IConnectionService connectionService,  
            IDialogService dialogService, ISxCaseDataService sxCaseDataService,
            IStaffDataService staffDataService) : base(connectionService,  dialogService)
        {
            _sxCaseDataService = sxCaseDataService;
            _staffDataService = staffDataService;

            SxCaseStaffJoin = _sxCaseStaffJoin;
            SxCaseStaffJoins = new ObservableCollection<SxCaseStaffJoin>();

            Title = "Staff";
            SxCaseStaffJoins = new ObservableCollection<SxCaseStaffJoin>();
            LoadSxCaseStaffJoinCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadSxCaseStaffJoinsCommand(Convert.ToInt32(sxCaseId)));
            RefreshSxCaseStaffJoinCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadSxCaseStaffJoins(Convert.ToInt32(sxCaseId)));

        }


        public SxCaseStaffJoin SxCaseStaffJoin
        {
            get => _sxCaseStaffJoin;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _sxCaseStaffJoin, value);
            }
        }

        public string SxCaseId
        {
            get
            {
                return sxCaseId;
            }
            set
            {
                sxCaseId = value;
                Task.Delay(500);
               
            }
        }

        private async Task ExecuteLoadSxCaseStaffJoinsCommand(int sxCaseId)
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                SxCaseStaffJoins.Clear();
                var sxCaseStaffJoins = await _staffDataService.GetSxCaseStaffJoinForSxCase(sxCaseId);
                foreach (var sxCaseStaffJoin in sxCaseStaffJoins)
                {
                    SxCaseStaffJoins.Add(sxCaseStaffJoin);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }

        private async Task LoadSxCaseStaffJoins(int sxCaseId)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            await Task.Delay(500);

            SxCaseStaffJoins = (ObservableCollection<SxCaseStaffJoin>)await _staffDataService.GetSxCaseStaffJoinForSxCase(sxCaseId);

            IsBusy = false;

        }

        
    }
```

}

---

Page

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:utility="clr-namespace:QiX.Utility;assembly=QiX"
             xmlns:iOsSpecific="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:QiX.ViewModels;assembly=QiX"
             x:Class="QiX.Views.StaffView"
             x:DataType="viewModels:StaffViewModel"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             utility:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             iOsSpecific:Page.UseSafeArea="True"
             x:Name="StaffPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RefreshView x:DataType="viewModels:StaffViewModel"  IsRefreshing="{Binding RefreshSxCaseStaffJoinCommand,IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ScrollView>
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding SxCaseStaffJoins}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell Text="{Binding SxCaseId}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                   
                </CollectionView>
            </ScrollView>
        </RefreshView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

---

Comment: Add `Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(StaffView)}?{nameof(StaffViewModel.SxCaseId)}={sxCase?.SxCaseId}");` - what is exact string shown in Output if you do that? (Maybe some problem in the syntax of passing a parameter - can't quite tell from the source)

Comment: Try changing `public string sxCaseId;` to `public string sxCaseId { get; set;}`. (Maybe that has to be a property, not just a field.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve the output is [0:] StaffViewModel?SxCaseId=11.  I tried changing the public string sxCaseId, but that did not work either.

Comment: To make sure there isn't some other problem:  If you hardcode StaffViewModel such that SxCaseId is already 11 (and don't pass in that parameter), does it work? So just go to "StaffViewModel".